# JDK 8 TreeView disclosure triangle vertical aligned not correctly

Tags: treeview, javafx-2, javafx, java-8

I make a custom tree cell which has height 40 px.

And here a problem disclosure triangle does not aligned center vertically.

[image]

Here code of tree cell:

```
public static class TestObjectCell extends AnchorPane implements ISMPBVisualComponentWithData<TestObject>{

        public Label label;

        public TestObjectCell(){
            label=new Label("label");
            AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(label, 10.0);
            this.getChildren().setAll(label);
            this.setMinHeight(40);
            this.setPrefHeight(40);
            this.setMaxHeight(40);
        }


        @Override
        public void setComponentData(TestObject object) {
            //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }



    }
```

As u can see at picture disclosure triangle aligned at top, how do align him vertical center of cell?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I used the cell factory to translate the disclosure node of the TreeCell:

```
myTree.setCellFactory(treeView -> {

        final TreeCell<Label> cell = new TreeCell<Label>() {
            @Override public void updateItem(Label item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);

                if (empty) {
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {
                    final Node graphic = (getTreeItem() == null) ? null : getTreeItem().getGraphic();
                    setGraphic((graphic != null) ? graphic : (item != null) ? item.getGraphic() : null);  
                }
                setText((empty || item == null) ? null : item.getText()); 
            }
        };          

        cell.disclosureNodeProperty().addListener((obs, oldNode, newNode) -> {
            final StackPane pane = (StackPane) newNode;
            newNode.translateYProperty().bind(cell.heightProperty().multiply(0.5).subtract(pane.heightProperty()));
        }); 
        return cell;
});
```

Surely there must be a better way to do this, but at least this worked for me.

Comment: For me worked more ideally these params: newNode.translateYProperty().bind(cell.heightProperty().multiply(0.5).subtract(pane.heightProperty().divide(1.25)));

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting [alignment property inside TreeCell](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#alignmentProperty%28%29) ?

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I have found to change the alignment of the disclosure node is to manually override the vertical padding using the `-fx-padding` style:

```
.tree-disclosure-node {
   -fx-padding: 0.85em 0.229em 0.333333em 0.229em;
}
```

This will allow you to get the arrow centered as needed, but you will need to modify this value if the row height ever changes.